# _addFunctionCall method in Javascript

Tags: javascript

Is there any method in JS named `_addFunctionCall` ? I came across following line in a legacy application.
Method defination:

```
i2b2.ONT.ajax._addFunctionCall( "GetNameInfo",
                                "{{{URL}}}getNameInfo", 
                                i2b2.ONT.cfg.msgs.GetNameInfo,
                                null,
                                i2b2.ONT.cfg.parsers.ExtractConcepts);
```

Method call:

```
var results = i2b2.ONT.ajax.GetNameInfo("ONT:FindBy", searchOptions);
```

My another question is `GetNameInfo` method call contains only two parameters while it seems that method defination contains more than two parameters.So how things work here ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. That appears to be code from the proprietary "i2b2.ONT" library; google for it; https://community.i2b2.org/wiki/display/NCBO/NCBO+Ontology+Tools
2. The number of arguments passed to a js function does not need to match the number the function was declared with.
   An argument not passed will be `undefined` within the function (just like any other uninitialized variable) & extra arguments can be read within the function via `arguments[ordinal]`.

Comment: I checked that site but it didnt help me much. Still will give another try.

Comment: No idea if its relevant to whatever your trying to do but googling for `+i2b2 "_addFunctionCall = function"` gave me http://informatics.kumc.edu/work/browser/i2b2-webclient/webclient/js-i2b2/hive/i2b2_cell_communicator.js?rev=c3ba49d2a1b276e91c796fc28bffeaeb7cb00b6e

Answer (score 0):

`_addFunctionCall` is not a native JavaScript method.

It appears that the application you are looking at the source code for, has its own function called `_addFunctionCall` that constructs a function based on the input arguments and adds it to the object.

Comment: I checked complete source code and couldn't find any place where `_addFunctionCall` is defined or used.

Answer (score 0):

It's not standard javascript.

you'll have to look for the definition of the i2b2.ONT.ajax object.

There are no method definitions in the code you posted, but two different methods calls :
- _addFunctionCall takes 5 parameters (at least)
- GetNameInfo takes two.

Answer (score 0):

_addFunctionCall is defined in the i2b2 hive's i2b2_cell_communicator.js file. Check the 1.7 source or whatever source you are using in your hive.